# Why WebServlets return 404 error when using Eclipse Webby plugin?

Tags: java, maven, war, sonatype, webby

I needed to combine maven war overlays with debugging Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse, so I've installed m2e-webby plugin. When I run it in eclipse, static content (html files) are launching properly, but when I enter WebServlet adress it's always gives 404 in return;
I've tried @WebServlet annotation and web.xml mappings as well.
I'm using Tomcat 7 but also tried it on Webby-embedded Jetty 7.

What is the proper config for project to make servlets work in Webby debug?

Greetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better try to use m2e-wtp: [Dev - M2E - WTP OSS](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP). It's easier and it works with Tomcat7 (include @WebServlet annotation).